# Discord.js v13 trying to make a button click event

Tags: node.js, button, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am trying to make a click button event in `discord.js` v13 but it won't work. Here is my code :

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async button => {
    if(button.CustomId === 'pricestore') {
        button.channel.send("test:")
        button.defer();
    }
})
```

Comment: Typo: `if(button.CustomId === 'pricestore')` should be `if(button.customId === 'pricestore')`. The 'C' should be small

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are also called Interactions, Discord has multiple types of Interactions, Slash Commands, Buttons, Modals, etc - they are all passed through this event and to create a bot with these types of features you will need to implement something similar to what is described below.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    // . . .
});
```

You will first need to create the listener for the `interactionCreate` event, this will allow the bot to listen for people using Interactions.

```js
.isApplicationCommand()
.isAutocomplete()
.isButton()
.isCommand()
.isContextMenu()
.isMessageComponent()
.isMessageContextMenu()
.isModalSubmit()
.isSelectMenu()
.isUserContextMenu()
```

All of the above functions can be used to determine what type of interaction it is that you are getting. We will be using the `isButton` function as that is what is shown in the question.

You will need to check the interaction type inside the event we created before and it will look like this:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        // . . .
    }
});
```

Now that we know we are getting a button event, we will want to check what button it is that is being clicked, doing this allows you to have multiple buttons as you can just add a new check for each of them.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if(intearction.customId == 'pricestore') {
                // . . .
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, we will send a message to the channel once the button is clicked.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if(intearction.customId == 'pricestore') {
                interaction.channel.send({ content: 'Test Message!' });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this was of help!